# Maven multi module project, why is "pom packaging" required?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I use eclipse to develop an app engine project on maven that require "war packaging" (using [maven-gae-plugin archetype](http://hamandeggs.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/how-to-gae-eclipse-maven/)).

How can I include other projects (e.g. a common library project) such a way that everything get updated when changes are done in one of the sub-projects ?

One solution could be "multi module project", but I don't understand why maven require the parent project to be pom packaging. Also, I am afraid that changing to pom packaging might break the appengine compatiblity (executing dev-server, deployment from eclipse plugin etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A multi-module project is not only a way of packaging library dependents projects, indeed a war or an ear. It allows you to share properties, plugins, behaviors ...

This is a way to link them together regardless of the final structure. Their own lifecycle are related.

So, the better way to do what you want is

```
/
|your-parent-project
+--pom.xml --> pom
|
+--/your-webapp-project
|  +--pom.xml --> war
|  
+--/your-service-project
|  +--pom.xml --> jar
|  
+--/your-dao-project
|  +--pom.xml --> jar
|  
+--/your-common-resources-project
|  +--pom.xml --> zip
```

You'll still deploy your war project, but parent project would contain information about team, CI, dependency management.

You'll release your parent project (with maven-release-plugin it will tag and guild automatically), because this it holds the whole lifecycle and relation between all of them..

Reactor (maven ordering engine) will arrange the order of building to match your dependencies, eg. resources, dao, services, webapp ...

You really should read the Sonatype's book : http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/.

Hope this little explaination will help you !

Answer (score 1):

A multi-module project is the way to do this. The war project should be a child module, and that project should use the gae-plugin. The parent project is just a descriptor of the relationship between the common library, the war, and any other projects you might include. In our application we have 2 war projects (1 for our website, 1 for some map-reduce things that run on another version of our app) a common code base (packaged as a jar) and an appengine-remote project that we use for utility functions.

The reason the parent is just a "pom" is that it's not deployed anywhere as runnable code.